# How find this all positive integer number $n=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$

Tags: number-theory

let $x,y,z,n$ is positive integer,and such
$$n=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz,n\le 2014$$

Find  all the  $n$ value

My idea: since
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$$

then I can't 
Thank you

Comment: Again, $$x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx)$$ So, if we choose $x+y+z$ as integer factor of $n,$ we can immediately find  $xy+yz+zx$

Comment: See the more general http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724990/integers-can-be-expressed-as-a3b3c3-3abc for a solution.