# Given integers $m,n$, find integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=m n$

Tags: diophantine-equations, determinant

With a³+b³+c³-3abc=m (m-random integer) 
And
a³+b³+c³-3abc=n(n-another integer)
How to find 
a³+b³+c³-3abc=m*n(m and n are Co prime) 
I came across this in an online math contest. 
Hint was given as properties of determinants. 
We have to find integer values of a, b, c which satisfy the equation
a³+b³+c³-3abc=m*n
(All three cases have different values for a,b,c)
(in online question numbers where used instead of m and n) 
Pls help

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. You might want to read this [informative tutorial on formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: How the expression $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ has three values: $m$, $n$ and $mn$?

Comment: 1 St one different a,b,c .

Comment: 2 nd one different a,b,c

Comment: 3 Rd one different a,b,c

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049581___

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to look at this. Take a three by three matrix
$$
T =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Note that
$$
T^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $$   T^3 = I$$

$$
aI + bT + cT^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b & c & a
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Using $T^3 = I, \; T^4 = T,$ given $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f),$ it is easy to calculate $(j,k,l)$ in
$$ (aI + b T + c T^2)(dI + eT + fT^2) = jI + kT + lT^2   $$
Meanwhile, we are using determinants, in that 
$$ \det(aI + b T + c T^2)  = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc   $$

Comment: Thank u so much

Comment: But how did u get a³+b³+c³-3abc 's determinant?